# Internet explorer css problem. (Hidden padding)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, doctype

I have created a little slider using jQuery UI, and it's works fantastically in Firefox, exactly as it should. However, in IE, it seems to put padding in between objects. Take a look and you'll see:

http://www.grant[deletethis]unwin.co.uk/slider/slider1.html

I understand that different broswers have different page margins and paddings set automatically, so I tried to use:

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

But the problem persists.

The Question:

how can I eliminate the gaps between the pictures on my slider (In IE)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your page is rendering in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), because you aren't using [a doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) (..that will trigger Standards Mode).

Your first line is currently this:

```
<html>
```

Add a doctype as the very first line, such as the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

It will be magically fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Please add a **valid Doctype** because your website is being viewed in *Quirks mode* in IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> .... </html>
```

**Additionaly**
Remove float for the `img` element itself and set `display: block;`

```
.scroller_item {
    float: left;
    height: 238px;
    width: 192px;
}

.scroller_item .image {
    display: block;
    height: 238px;
    width: 192px;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the first (now second) part of your answer ;)

Comment: @thirtydot: True that, though inline images are famous for leaving a 3px gap (usually at the bottom) so display: block fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a reset to put all the styles back to zero in all browsers. Using that should fix your problem.
[Eric Meyer's Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
*
{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: none;
}

#sliding_section
{
  overflow: auto;
}
```

You'll have to tweak the `*` properties, as this will be bad for a production site, but it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "float:left" in your ".scroller_item .image" definition in your CSS class.