# How to create a table-like CSS layout with DIVs?

Tags: javascript, css, layout

### UPDATE 2

I found a tentative solution that currently works for me in Chrome on Mac OS X. [You can check out my answer below for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720552/complicated-css-layout-need-some-help/5724006#5724006). For those of you who are still trying to come up with CSS only solutions or JavaScript solutions, please keep going and let me know what you come up with! Please :)

### UPDATE

The answer below is really close to an all CSS solution, so I'm going to try to make it work. In the meantime, I'm opening up this question to JavaScript solutions as well. How would you do it using JavaScript? All solutions are now welcome :)

---

Let's see if we can solve this one together!

I'm trying to set up a layout, check out the image...

[image: layout]

I'm using the "sticky footer" technique, which works great, and I've set it up so that whenever one of the two columns gets taller, the other will also match its height, [as described in this article](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-2-column.htm). The problem, however, is that these two columns don't reach the footer naturally... I'm forcing the height through JavaScript.

Anyway, all the relevant code can be seen in the fiddle...

### CODE

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/XrJMa/embedded/result/

### QUESTIONS

1. **First big problem**: how can I set it up so that the height of these columns reaches the footer below? I want it so that when the page loads, both pink and blue columns reach the bottom automatically.
2. How can I get it so that when the pink column grows beyond its current height, a local scrollbar appears, but when the blue column grows beyond its current height, the overall page scrollbar appears and the footer is pushed down?

```
- basically, I want the height of the pink and blue columns to ALWAYS be the same height but the height is only determined by the blue column; blue is dominant so it can expand the height of both columns; pink cannot expand the height, just be at the same height as blue
```

3. Can this functionality be achieved using only CSS?

Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to stick with the JS option? JS is really the best way to handle complex vertical spacing and alignment as CSS doesn't have a lot of abilities in that realm.

Comment: yo DA... really the only reason is because I wanted to try doing this using only CSS, kind of as a challenge; it would be really neat to do it using only CSS. however, I'm going to update my question so you can go ahead and do some damage using JavaScript. let's see what you got :)

Comment: @Hristo, will the box always be the same width?

Comment: @Marko... which box are you referring to? For right now, let's go with yes.

Comment: well, it'd certainly be a challenge, but I'm a fan of pragmatic web design. ;o) This is a solution for a screwdriver when CSS is the hammer. The JS logic would be to calculate the height of both divs, then change the one that is shorter to match the one that is longer by setting it's height. Additional logic could be added to handle your other variables. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @DA... I know how to do it, but syntactically I don't. What I mean by that is I don't know how to actually get heights of elements and positions in JavaScript, but I know the logic of how to solve the problem :) that said, yes of course I'm using jQuery :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your [most recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720552/complicated-css-layout-need-some-help/5724006#5724006), I take it you don't need the footer to be full width (only sticky, though yours isn't) and also I presume you know that your version will only work if you know the height of the "foo - not so important content", as you need the that height to set the top co-ordinate for the sidebar .

You version falls down in that when you narrow the window content disappears off the sides.. but based on the thinking behind it - I've used your logic extended it and built in the sticky footer, top menu - everything that was in the original example link.

the footer's not full width, <strike>but you can make it look like it is by putting a background image on the `html` element, I have a plain dummy image in my fiddle but it's not showing up, anyway you would make an image the same height/color as the footer with the 1px border built in</strike>

this absolutely relies on you being able to fix/calculate the height of everything above the pink/blue columns

there is a lot less container divs needed for this and the content is now before the sidebar in the source

#### Here's the fiddle : [fullsize](http://fiddle.jshell.net/clairesuzy/qe6P8/show/) : [to edit](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/qe6P8/)

Comment: @clairesuzy... this is not quite what I'm looking for. 1) Thank you for pointing out that my solution fails when narrowing the window, that is easily fixed with `min-width`. 2) My solution does have a sticky footer, but it seems to not be working in Firefox quite right. 3) your solution fails when the content in the content in the blue area gets to large... http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/qe6P8/2/embedded/result/ ... when I say sticky footer, I don't mean ALWAYS be on the bottom, only when there is not enough content to push it to the bottom. check out http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: @Hristo I don't understand, it was working and is again ;).. I have updated the links in my answer to have a JS toggle to show/hide content, my footer is sticky, but the background image idea (to fake the full page width) didn't work in FF so I've removed it, the footer itself does actually only stick to the bottom only if content is too short.

Comment: @clairesuzy... haha awesome. I think this is correct, but I need to play around with it a bit more. I'll get back to you. Thanks for making the changes!

Comment: btw... awesome job! I wish I could upvote you multiple times. It works great in your example, exactly what I'm looking for. I'm going to try and integrate it with my project and hopefully it all works out. many thanks!

Comment: @clairesuzy... what is the CSS property `xheight`?

Comment: @Hristo there isn't one.. my bad.. i add an x  when testing to quickly remove a property - you can just delete it.. I had the top div at fixed height before I added the tabs **sorry**

Comment: @clairesuzy... thank you :) you also have a weird CSS property, `ul#menu li {display: inline !ie7;}` what does this do? if this does what I think it does, shouldn't it be in the conditional stylesheet?

Comment: Yes you can feed it to `lte IE7` in a conditional stylesheet (doesn't need the `!ie7` in conditional sheet).. it's the hack that makes IE7 and below honour `inline-block` on block level elements - either way, hack or conditional sheet, it **cannot** go in the same ruleset as the `inline-block` rule (e.g. via a `*` hack) unless the element already has hasLayout `:)`

Comment: @clairesuzy... thank you! I haven't tested in IE but I don't plan on it for now. Anyway, I have another challenge for you :) check out this question... http://stackoverflow.com/q/5768029/196921

Answer (score 2):

There were many issues, so I rewrote it. I have created exactly what you want. Enjoy. =)

http://jsfiddle.net/hRkx8/53/

**The trick is to have your main region have a margin-bottom the same height as your footer (which you absolutely position). Thus as your blue thing gets larger, it will start pushing the bottom of the page a bit earlier than it normally would.**

(edit: this version moves the footer, which is more difficult to do; however the question asked that the blue area be initialized to be as large as possible, see below for one way to do this)

---

Here we go! Unfortunately I have to include it inline, since jsfiddle has some severe bugs that prevent proper display. This version has the blue area start all the way at the bottom.

absolutely-positioned elements seem to have some trouble automatically scrolling as the page gets bigger, so I created a dummy #main div much like you did and had it fill the entire viewport, then inside that is both the #footer and #content (your blue and red stuff). The #footer is absolutely positioned so it takes up no space / the document doesn't care about it. As the #content expands, the #main container expands with it, dragging the footer along. The use of a margin-bottom is necessary to prevent the footer from hiding text.

The actual amount of CSS required to do this is, if you remove the demo stuff, just about 5 lines and dummy element.

```
<html>
<head>

<style>

body {
    margin:0; padding:0;
}

* { /* just for demonstration */
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px dashed red;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px; -moz-border-radius:10px;
    background-color:hsla(0,50%,50%, 0.1);
}

/*important to use min-height not height*/

#main {
    position:relative; width:100%; min-height:100%;
    border:3px solid green;
}
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; height:5em; /*can be anything*/
    background-color:lightgrey;
}

#content {
    position:relative;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:skyblue;
    margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;
    padding-bottom:5em; /*must be same as #footer's height*/
    margin-top:10%; /*browser bug: actually acts like 20%*/
    width:50%;
    min-height:80%; /*should equal 100%-marginTop*/
    border:3px solid blue;
}
/* dependent elements */
#sidebar {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px; bottom:0px;
    right:100%; width:7em;
    background-color:pink;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
#topbar {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100%; height:3em;
    right:-10%; left:10%;    
}

</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

setTimeout("$('pre').animate({height:1500}, 3000)", 1000);  

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="everything">
    <div id="main">

        <div id="content">
            <div id="sidebar">
                alpha
                <br/>
                beta
                <br/>
                gamma
                <br/>
                etc.
            </div>
            <div id="topbar">
                Menu1 * Menu2 * Menu3 * ...
            </div>
            This is my site.
            Yay.
            <pre>
            etc.
            etc.
            etc.
            etc.
            etc.
            etc.
            etc.
            etc.
            etc.
            etc.
            etc.
            etc.
            etc.
            etc.
            etc.
            etc.
            etc.
            </pre>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            footer
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do I get the blue column to initially reach the footer in terms of height?

Comment: You did not ask for that. =) So unfortunately it's a bit harder. If I had known I would have made it be that way. Let me ponder it for a tiny bit.

Comment: @ninjagecko... I did ask that... `First big problem: how can I set it up so that the height of these columns reaches the footer below? I want it so that when the page loads, both pink and blue columns reach the bottom automatically.`

Comment: @ninjagecko... ponder away :) there is no rush, besides the desire to get this to work :)

Comment: solved, enjoy =) (you can tweak the values a tiny bit so the scrollbars don't show up at the start) edit: just added overflow-y:scroll;

Comment: @ninjagecko... that looks legit. I'm going to try to integrate it with my stuff. I'll let you know if it worked or not. In the meantime, would you mind giving a brief explanation on what you did?

Comment: absolutely-positioned elements seem to have some trouble automatically scrolling as the page gets bigger, so I created a dummy #main div much like you did and had it fill the entire viewport, then inside that is both the #footer and #content (your blue and red stuff). The #footer is absolutely positioned so it takes up no space / the document doesn't care about it. As the #content expands, the #main container expands with it, dragging the footer along. The use of a margin-bottom is necessary to prevent the footer from hiding text.

Comment: A random note: please remember to always include a doctype to ensure your page isn't in Quirks Mode. For more information, see some of my answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a405015%20%5bdoctype%5d - like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669077/internet-explorer-css-problem-hidden-padding/5669132#5669132

Answer (score 2):

Is it just me, or is the pink elephant in the room sitting on a ...

< T A B L E >

???

**Update (April 20th, 11:40AM):**  Here's the <table> version:

http://juliusdavies.ca/stackoverflow/pink_elephant.html

Be sure to resize your browser window a few times to see it in action.

- IE8 - perfect
- Chrome - perfect
- Safari - no scrollbar, otherwise okay
- Firefox - no scrollbar, otherwise okay

Comment: don't see any elephants, especially pink ones

Comment: <TABLE>? Probably not. Display: Table? Certainly a valid option.

Comment: +1 to DA.... ROTFL!  Let me see if I understand correctly? <table> no good, but <div class='table'><div class='tr'><div class='td'> is okay????

Comment: Does <table> become acceptable if we set *it* in CSS to anything EXCEPT display: table?  Is a 'display:block' table okay?

Answer (score 0):

I see this as a design having a top a middle and a footer. The middle section contains both the pink and blue columns.

1. Using CSS, place a repeating image in the background of the middle-section behind both the left and right columns. This image would show the edges of both columns. Hopefully your design will accommodate this. I admit I do not know, without really digging into the code, how to make the middle expand all the way down to the bottom. I should think there are some different ways to approach this.
2. Use css overflow: auto; for your pink column; for the blue, set overflow: auto; on the  or  tag.
3. I hope this helps...

Comment: @Greg... thanks for your response. Its not quite as simple as top, middle, footer. I wish :) It is more of a large top and a footer such that two are dependent on each other.

Comment: @Hristo...this was the solution to something I did a few weeks ago. I thought it might fit your need. In my solution I needed to have a special look to the top and bottom. But it was floating in the middle of the page instead of the whole page; not exactly your need. Be well

Comment: @Greg... thank you. I'm glad it worked out for you. However, I need to keep working at my solution.